# Error when running playbook

Tags: ansible

Getting an error message when running my first playbook. I created a playbook to apply patch on multiple hosts.

```
---
- hosts: server01

  vars:
    jboss_home: /apps/middleware/jboss-eap-7.1
    patch_file: patch_url
    patch_dest: /apps/middleware/jboss-eap-7.1
    patch_version: 7.1.3

  tasks:

  - name: Copy patch to target host
    copy:
      src: "{{ patch_file }}"
      dest: "{{ patch_dest }}/{{ patch_file }}"

  - name: Check applied patches
    command: "jboss-cli.sh 'patch history'"
    register: result
    changed_when: "False"

  - name: Apply patch
    command: "jboss-cli.sh 'patch apply {{ patch_dest }}/{{ patch_file }}'"
    when: patch_version not in result.stdout
```

**Output**

> Fatal error  PLAY [server1]
>   ****************************************************************************************** TASK [Gathering Facts]
>   *********************************************************************************************************** ok: [server1] TASK [Copy patch to target host]
>   ************************************************************************************************* An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full
>   traceback, use -vvv. The error was:
>   /apps/middleware/ansible/environments/dev/jboss/patching/patch_url
>   fatal: [server1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find
>   or access 'patch_url'\nSearched
>   in:\n\t/apps/middleware/ansible/environments/dev/jboss/patching/files/patch_url\n\t/apps/middleware/ansible/environments/dev/jboss/patching/patch_url\n\t/apps/middleware/ansible/environments/dev/jboss/patching/files/patch_url\n\t/apps/middleware/ansible/environments/dev/jboss/patching/patch_url"}
>           to retry, use: --limit @/apps/middleware/ansible/environments/dev/jboss/patching/jboss_patching.retry

Comment: Well, the root cause of the error is written in the message `Could not find or access 'patch_url'` the `copy` module can't find this file.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the url now i`m getting this error failed: [server1] (item=http://artifacts-scm.net/artifactory/middleware/jboss/jboss                                            {"changed": false, "dest": "/apps/middleware/jboss-eap-7.1", "gid": 1041, "group": "mwadm", "item": "http                         net/artifactory/middleware/jboss/jboss-eap-7.1.3-patch.zip", "mode": "0775", "msg": "Request failed      t>", "owner": "mwadm", "secontext": "system_u:object_r:etc_runtime_t:s0", "size": 238, "state": "director   http://artifacts-scm.net/artifactory/middleware/jboss/jboss-eap-7.1.3-patch.zip"}

Answer (score 0):

`patch_url` file should be present in the `files` directory of your `patching` role.
As stated in the output, that is where `copy` module is looking for it by default, then in the root of your role.

Comment: Thanks, got that fixed now error failed: [server1] (item=http://artifacts-scm.net/artifactory/middleware/jboss/jboss                                            {"changed": false, "dest": "/apps/middleware/jboss-eap-7.1", "gid": 1041, "group": "mwadm", "item": "http net/artifactory/middleware/jboss/jboss-eap-7.1.3-patch.zip", "mode": "0775", "msg": "Request failed t>", "owner": "mwadm", "secontext": "system_u:object_r:etc_runtime_t:s0", "size": 238, "state": "director   http://artifacts-scm.net/artifactory/middleware/jboss/jboss-eap-7.1.3-patch.zip"}

Comment: "mode": "0775", "msg": "Request failed: <urlopen error timed out>", "owner": "mwadm", "secontext": "system_u:object_r:etc_runtime_t:s0", "size": 238, "state": "directory", "uid": 1040, "url": " my url - "http://artifacts-scm.net/artifactory/middleware/jboss/jboss-eap-7.1.3-patch.zip"